# How would I create a HashMap for a TicTacToe game

Tags: java, hashmap, cells

I am creating a TicTacToe game with 2 boards, only one is playable to the user. If a user clicks on cell[2][3] on grid 1 a token will be drawn on grid 1 and on cells[2][3] on grid 2. I was thinking of using a HashMap to assign indexes to each cell. Like cell[2][3] and cells[2][3] would each be assigned to index 9. How would I implement this is my code? Would I even use a Hashmap for what I am trying to do? I am unfamiliar with this concept so I might just be overthinking this. 
Note: Cell[][] is the cells for grid 1 and Cells[][] are for grid 2. Cells[][] have randomized indexes in it so it can be randomly assigned to the board.

Edit: If I want to link cell(2)(3) and cells(2)(3) I would change integer to Cell when I initialize hashmap. Then I would do HMap. put(cell[2][3], cells[2][3]) right?

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Bull extends JFrame{
   private char currentPlayer = ' ';
   // Creates array of cells called Cell[][] cell
   private Cell[][] cell = new Cell[3][3];
   // Creates array of cells called Sale[][] cells
   private Cells[][] cells = new Cells[3][3];
   // Creates a boolean array
   private boolean t[][] = new boolean[3][3];
   // Creates index array
   private int z[] = new int[8];
   //Initializes Random
   Random rand = new Random();
   // Initializes variables which will be used to create random ints
   int f;
   int g;
   // Initializes JlblStatus
   private JLabel jlblStatus = new JLabel(" ");
   private JLabel jlblIndex = new JLabel(" ");
   // Method that builds the JFrame and JPanels
   public Bull(){
      // Do I change Integer to array?
      HashMap<Integer, Integer> HMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
      // Title of the JFrame
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shadow Tic Tac Toe Game");
      // Makes the JFrame full screen
      frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      // If x button is clicked than the JFrame closes
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      // Initializes JPanel1
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      // Initializes JPanel2
      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

      // Adds panel1 which will hold the first TicTacToe game.
      panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,0,0));
      for(int d = 0; d < 3; d++){
         for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++){
            panel1.add(cell[d][c] = new Cell());
            // Sets size of the cells in JPanel1
            cell[d][c].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,250));
         }
      }




      panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,0,0));
      int n = 0;
      while(n < 9){
      f=rand.nextInt(3);
      g=rand.nextInt(3);
      while(t[f][g] == false){
         t[f][g] = true;
         panel2.add(cells[f][g] = new Cells());
         cells[f][g].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,250));
         System.out.println(f);
         System.out.println("\t" + g);
         n++;

        }
       }








      // Adds Panel1 to the JFrame
      frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
      // Adds Panel2 to the JFrame
      frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.EAST);
      // Updates the status of the game here (win/lose/draw/whose turn it is
      frame.add(jlblStatus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      // Sets size of the message area at the bottom of the frame
      jlblStatus.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
      // Shows the Instructions of the game
      Instructions();
      // Calls method Chose() which allows the player to chose which token they will play as
      Chose();
      frame.pack();
      // Sets it so the JFrame is visible to the user
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }


   // Method that creates the Instructions for the game. Will be shown to the user prior to the user picking his token
   public void Instructions(){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"INSTRUCTIONS" + "\nThis game is called a 'Shadow Tic Tac Toe Game'. In this game there will be two Tic Tac Toe game boards, though only one is playable. \nBut you can win on either board. Lets say you place your token on the center tile at cell(2,3). \nAn X will be drawn on that spot on board 1 and on a randomized spot on the second game board at cell(2,3). \nYou will be able to see the cell indexes before you click on a cell so you can form a strategy");
   }
   // Method that lets the user chose his/her token
   public void Chose(){
      int f = 2;
      // While f == 2 the loop will run
      while(f == 2){
         String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("CHOSE" + "\nPlease select your token. \nPress 1 for X and 2 for O.");
         // Reads in the user input. Input put into a variable called pawn
         int pawn = Integer.parseInt(input);
         // If user input 1 his/her token will be X. F will equal 3 so the loop does not run again
         if(input.equals("1")){
            currentPlayer = 'X';
            f = 3;
         // If user input 2 his/her token will be O. F will equal 3 so the loop does not run again
         }else if(input.equals("2")){
            currentPlayer = 'O';
            f = 3;
         // If user does not enter in either a 1 or 2 an error message will appear. f wil equal 2 so the loop runs again and asks the user to chose his/her token again
         }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR INVALID RESPONSE");
            f = 2;
      }
     }
   }
   public class Cells extends JPanel{
      private char tok = ' ';
      public Cells(){
         // Sets the border for the cells to the color black
         setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,1));
      }
      public void setTok(char d){
         tok = d;
         repaint();
      }
      public char getTok(){
         return tok;
      }
      protected void Paint(Graphics g){
         super.paint(g);

         if(tok == 'X'){
            g.drawLine(10,10,getWidth() - 10, getHeight()-10);
            g.drawLine(getWidth()-10,10,10,getHeight()-10);
         }else if (tok == 'O'){
            g.drawOval(10,10,getWidth()-20, getHeight()-20);
         }
      }
   }
    public class Cell extends JPanel{
      private char token = ' ';
      public void setToken(char c){
         token = c;
         repaint();
      }
      public char getToken(){
         return token;
      }
      public Cell(){ 
         // Sets the border for the cells to the color black
         setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
         addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
      }
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);

         if (token == 'X') {
           g.drawLine(10,10, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10);
           g.drawLine(getWidth() - 10,10,10, getHeight() - 10);
         }
         else if (token == 'O') {
           g.drawOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
         }
      } 
      private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter{
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        // If cell is empty and game is not over
        if (token == ' ' && currentPlayer != ' ') {
          setToken(currentPlayer); // Set token in the cell
          for(int d = 0; d < 3; d++){
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++){
               if(cell[d][c].getToken() == 'X'){
                  cells[d][c].setTok('X');
               }else if(cell[d][c].getToken() == 'O'){
                  cells[d][c].setTok('O');
               }else if(cell[d][c].getToken() == ' '){
                  cells[d][c].setTok(' ');
               }
            }
          }
          //setTok(currentPlayer); 
               if(Won(currentPlayer)){
                  jlblStatus.setText("The game is over! " + currentPlayer + " won the game! Congragulations " + currentPlayer + " !");
                  currentPlayer = ' ';
               }else if(Full()){
                  jlblStatus.setText("The game is over, it ends in a draw!");
                  currentPlayer = ' ';
               }else{
                   if(currentPlayer == 'X'){
                     currentPlayer = 'O';
                   }else{
                     currentPlayer = 'X';
                   }

                  jlblStatus.setText("It is " + currentPlayer + " 's turn");  
               }

             }
         }
      }  
   }

   public boolean Full(){
      for(int d = 0; d < 3; d++)
         for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
            if(cell[d][c].getToken() == ' ')
               return false;
            return true;

    }

   public boolean Won(char token){
      for(int d = 0; d < 3; d++){
         if(cell[d][0].getToken() == token && cell[d][1].getToken() == token && cell[d][2].getToken() == token){
            return true;
         }
      }
      for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++){
         if(cell[0][c].getToken() == token && cell[1][c].getToken() == token && cell[2][c].getToken() == token){
            return true;
         }
       }
      if(cell[0][0].getToken() == token && cell[1][1].getToken() == token && cell[2][2].getToken() == token){
         return true;
      }
      if(cell[0][2].getToken() == token && cell[1][1].getToken() == token && cell[2][0].getToken() == token){
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
     public static void main(String [] args){
      new Bull();
   }
}
```

Comment: `new HashMap<>()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially you want to map a cell on one grid (that the player can play on) to some cell on another grid (the shadow grid)?

You could do this just using another 2D array that stores what indices a cell  maps to in the other grid, but you would need to return a point object containing x and y coordinates. But that method is sorta annoying to keep track of and has its limitations.

If you want to do it with a `HashMap<Point, Point>` of one `Point` in one grid to a `Point` in another grid, then you would have to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` of `Point` and do something like this:

```
HashMap<Point, Point> mapPointToPoint = new HashMap<>();

// (0,0) maps to shadow grid (1,2)
mapPointToPoint.put(new Point(0,0), new Point(1,2));
mapPointToPoint.put(new Point(0,1), new Point(2,1));
// ... more mappings for all the cells

// to get 
Point pointInPlayableGrid = new Point(0,0);
Point pointInShadowGrid = mapPointToPoint.get(pointInPlayableGrid);
// pointInShadowGrid == (1,2) since that's what it was mapped to
```

However, if you wanted to have multiple shadow grids then you'd need to have a map from points in the playable grid to the points in the shadow grids for each shadow grid.

So instead, since you already have the `Cell` class, why not just have each `Cell` store a `List<Cell>` of all the cells that it maps to. This is also very flexible because you could even have a single playable `Cell` map to multiple cells in a single shadow grid, and on hover of the playable `Cell` you could just go through the list of shadow `Cells` it maps to and highlight them too.

```
public class Cell extends JPanel{
    private Cell shadowCell;
    public void setCellThisMapsTo(Cell otherCell){ this.shadowCell = otherCell; }
    public Cell getCellThisMapsTo(){ return shadowCell; }
    // ... all the other stuff
}

// ... wherever you initialize the playable and shadow grid
// get a list of the shadow Cells, randomized order
Cell[][] shadowGrid; // however you init this
Cell[][] playableGrid; // however you init this

LinkedList<Cell> shadowCells = new LinkedList<>();
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
        shadowCells.add(shadowGrid[x][y]);
    }
}
Collections.shuffle(shadowCells);

for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
        Cell playableCell = playableGrid[x][y];
        Cell shadowCell = shadowCells.removeFirst();
        playableCell.setCellThisMapsTo(shadowCell );
    }
}

// Now all the playable cells map to a random shadow cell
Cell playableCell = playableGrid[0][0];
Cell shadowCell = playableCell.getCellThisMapsTo();
```

The shadow `Cells` will not map to any other cells, so `shadowCell.getCellThisMapsTo()` would return `null`. But this method would makes it easy to map playable cells to shadow cells and keep track of them, without even using a `HashMap` nor having to keep track of `Point`s mapping to `Point`s.

---

Here is my definition for `Point`. If you want to put something in a hash map based on its values (rather than its object reference), then it is important to override `hashCode()` and `equals()`:

```
class Point {
    public final int x;
    public final int y;
    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // !!! OVERRIDE hashCode() and equals() so  you can use this properly in a HashMap !!!
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 71 * hash + this.x;
        hash = 71 * hash + this.y;
        return hash;
    }

     @Override
    public int equals(Object o) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        Point p = (Point) o;
        return this.x == p.x && this.y == p.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: so Collections.shuffle(shadowCells) shuffle the cells so they are on random spots on the shadowgrid. So I would not have to use random ints I could just use Colelctions.shuffle, right?

Comment: @fzk Yep, it will just shuffle the list of shadow cells for you. And your playable Cells will have a reference to the shadow cell they link to. Please accept, if this answered your questions.